# How to find an integer between 1 and 1,100,000,000 divisible by two given integers by input (C)

Tags: c

I have a homework assignment that is to find and integer between 1 and 1,100,000,000 that is divisible by two inputted numbers from the user. I have seen many threads on finding the GCD of two given integers but never one that seems to do it in reverse as this one does. Any help?

Comment: You want [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), not GCD.

Comment: Why don't you just multiply the inputs together to get that number...

Comment: See [help/on-topic], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

Since you have seen threads of GCD, then i will suggest that to find LCM simply divide the number n by the GCD. Reason:

### LCM* GCD=NUMBER(n)

So to write a program for a number n that is divisible by two user input value you must do it in following way:

```
if(n%LCM==0){
   printf("The number is divisible\n");
}
else {
    printf("number is not divisible");
}
```